# Too much white space when using the align-environment

Tags: spacing, equations, align

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    \prod a+bm      && \text{is a square in} && \mathbb{R}\\
    \prod a+b\theta && \text{is a square in} && \mathbb{R}[\theta]
    \end{align}

    \begin{eqnarray}
    \prod a+bm      & \text{is a square in} & \mathbb{R}\\
    \prod a+b\theta & \text{is a square in} & \mathbb{R}[\theta]
    \end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The amount of white spce used by `eqnarray` is exactly what I want, whereas `align` adds a (in my opinion) freakishly large amount of white space. So I could just stick with `eqnarray`, but I've read that I should always (under any circumstances) refrain from using it.

So my question is, how do I make my equation look nice using `align`?

Comment: Why do you use two ampersands in the align environment and not just one?

Comment: @malin Because if I use only one, then everything looks very messy.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use the `alignat` environment, which is similar to `align`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
    \prod a+bm      &\quad \text{is a square in} &&\quad\mathbb{R}\\
    \prod a+b\theta &\quad \text{is a square in} &&\quad\mathbb{R}[\theta]
  \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

In the »[Math mode](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathmode)« document you can find more about advanced math typesetting.

---

[image]

---

**Update:**

As requested the same example but with all columns left aligned.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat}{3}
    &\prod a+bm      &&\quad \text{is a square in} &&\quad\mathbb{R}\\
    &\prod a+b\theta &&\quad \text{is a square in} &&\quad\mathbb{R}[\theta]
  \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Great, just one more question: Is it possible to have the two products, i.e. the capital PIs, right underneath each other (just like the two Rs are right underneath each other)?

Comment: @Tom: I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is it possible to have center-aligned equations with *alignat*, as in the original question? Or only flushed left?

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}                                                                      
  \prod a+bm &\phantom{=} \text{is a square in}\quad \mathbb{R}\\                  
  \prod a+b\theta &\phantom{=} \text{is a square in}\quad \mathbb{R}[\theta]       
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Flush left as requested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{lflalign}{%                                                         
  \def\align@preamble{%                                                             
    &\strut@                                                                        
    \setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{####}$}%                                   
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi                                               
    \set@field                                                                      
    \hfil                                                                           
    \tabskip\z@skip                                                                 
    &\setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{}####}$}%                                
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi                                               
    \set@field                                                                      
    \hfil                                                                           
    \tabskip\alignsep@                                                              
  }                                                                                 
  \flalign}
{\endflalign}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align}                                                                       
  \prod a+bm & \phantom{=}\text{is a square in}\quad \mathbb{R}\\                   
  \prod a+b\theta & \phantom{=}\text{is a square in}\quad \mathbb{R}[\theta]        
\end{align}
\begin{lflalign}
  \prod a+bm & \phantom{=}\text{is a square in}\quad \mathbb{R}\\
  \prod a+b\theta & \phantom{=}\text{is a square in}\quad \mathbb{R}[\theta]
\end{lflalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]